# Multi views switcher Android

Tags: android

In my app I have an activity that can show a list or one of several empty view (loading, sign in, error, etc)

I was looking for something like this:

```
public static class MultipleViewSwitcher {
    private final ArrayList<View> mViews;

    MultipleViewSwitcher(Activity activity, int... viewIds) {
        mViews = new ArrayList<>(viewIds.length);
        for (int id: viewIds) {
            mViews.add(activity.findViewById(id));
        }
    }

    public void showView(int viewId) {
        for (View view: mViews) {
            view.setVisibility(view.getId() == viewId ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewFlipper seems overkill because I do not need special animations.
Is there any native component to do it?

Comment: And why are you not satisfied with the code you show there?

Comment: It just seems such a common use case that I was expecting to find a native component to handle it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewritten your code a bit so you won't have to iterate through all your views

```
    public static class MultipleViewSwitcher {
    private final HashMap<Integer, View> mViews;
    private int currentView = -1;

    MultipleViewSwitcher(Activity activity, int... viewIds) {
        mViews = new HashMap<>();
        for (int id: viewIds) {
            mViews.put(id, activity.findViewById(id));
        }
    }

    public void showView(int viewId) {
        if (currentView != viewId) {
            if (currentView != -1)
                mViews.get(currentView).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mViews.get(viewId).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            currentView = viewId;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In some cases the version with ArrayList will be faster though because you do not need to create the map that most of the times won't be used. Maybe I should lazy initialize the collection to avoid findById and the creation of the map...